# Strange errors when installing my gem

Tags: ruby, rubygems, gemspecs

I just released v2.0.0 of the ginjo-rfm gem. When I install this gem on a stock Snow Leopard machine (rubygems version 1.3.5), I get the following error:

```
admin$ sudo gem install ginjo-rfm --no-rdoc --no-ri
ERROR:  Error installing ginjo-rfm:
    multi_json requires RubyGems version >= 1.3.6
```

However, the gem installs and runs successfully.

I have only one runtime dependency: ActiveSupport >= 2.3.5, and this is already installed on all of my machines. There is nowhere in my gem that I even mention multi_json.

Even stranger, when I try to install ginjo-rfm on Ubuntu 8.10 (rubygems version 1.3.5), rubygems throws a buffer overflow error (See Below).

What's wrong with my gem? It's a fairly straightforward gem & gemspec. I've combed thru it and cannot find any issues that would cause these kinds of errors.

If anyone would care to have a look at the raw gem:

```
mkdir ginjo; cd ginjo
gem fetch ginjo-rfm
tar -xf ginjo-rfm-2.0.0.gem
```

Or, see the gemspec as embedded as yaml in the 'metadata' file (See Below).

Thanks!

**Buffer Overflow Error**

```
~$ sudo gem install ginjo-rfm --no-rdoc --no-ri
*** buffer overflow detected ***: /usr/local/bin/ruby terminated
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc.so.6(__fortify_fail+0x48)[0xf76bf558]
/lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc.so.6[0xf76bd680]
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.8/i686-linux/syck.so(rb_syck_mktime+0x545)[0xf752cdb5]
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.8/i686-linux/syck.so(yaml_org_handler+0xabc)[0xf752d8dc]
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.8/i686-linux/syck.so(syck_defaultresolver_node_import+0x3f)[0xf752d9af]
/usr/local/bin/ruby[0x8060c74]
/usr/local/bin/ruby[0x8060e14]
/usr/local/bin/ruby[0x8061a5a]
/usr/local/bin/ruby(rb_funcall+0x20)[0x8061b90]
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.8/i686-linux/syck.so(rb_syck_load_handler+0x69)[0xf752b269]
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.8/i686-linux/syck.so(syck_hdlr_add_node+0x4d)[0xf7525edd]
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.8/i686-linux/syck.so(syckparse+0xc11)[0xf7526cb1]
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.8/i686-linux/syck.so(syck_parse+0x32)[0xf7522e12]
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.8/i686-linux/syck.so(syck_parser_load+0x112)[0xf752dd92]
/usr/local/bin/ruby[0x8056ecd]
/usr/local/bin/ruby[0x8060c74]
/usr/local/bin/ruby[0x8060e14]
/usr/local/bin/ruby[0x805ba84]
/usr/local/bin/ruby[0x805cd31]
/usr/local/bin/ruby[0x8060b79]
/usr/local/bin/ruby[0x8060e14]
/usr/local/bin/ruby[0x805ba84]
/usr/local/bin/ruby[0x805cd31]
/usr/local/bin/ruby[0x8060b79]
/usr/local/bin/ruby[0x8060e14]
/usr/local/bin/ruby[0x805ba84]
/usr/local/bin/ruby[0x805e605]
/usr/local/bin/ruby[0x8060b79]
/usr/local/bin/ruby[0x8060e14]
/usr/local/bin/ruby[0x805bb9c]
/usr/local/bin/ruby[0x805cde1]
/usr/local/bin/ruby[0x805e766]
/usr/local/bin/ruby[0x805f412]
/usr/local/bin/ruby[0x805be2d]
/usr/local/bin/ruby[0x805f412]
/usr/local/bin/ruby[0x8069ac5]
/usr/local/bin/ruby[0x8060c74]
/usr/local/bin/ruby[0x8060e14]
/usr/local/bin/ruby[0x805bb9c]
/usr/local/bin/ruby[0x805ec18]
/usr/local/bin/ruby[0x8060b79]
/usr/local/bin/ruby[0x8060e14]
/usr/local/bin/ruby[0x805ba84]
/usr/local/bin/ruby[0x805ec18]
/usr/local/bin/ruby[0x8060b79]
/usr/local/bin/ruby[0x8060e14]
/usr/local/bin/ruby(rb_obj_call_init+0x49)[0x8061779]
/usr/local/bin/ruby(rb_class_new_instance+0x2a)[0x808b53a]
/usr/local/bin/ruby[0x8056ecd]
/usr/local/bin/ruby[0x8060c74]
/usr/local/bin/ruby[0x8060e14]
/usr/local/bin/ruby(rb_call_super+0x68)[0x8068de8]
/usr/local/bin/ruby[0x80603ad]
/usr/local/bin/ruby[0x8060e14]
/usr/local/bin/ruby[0x805bb9c]
/usr/local/bin/ruby[0x805cd31]
/usr/local/bin/ruby[0x805e766]
/usr/local/bin/ruby[0x8060b79]
/usr/local/bin/ruby[0x8060e14]
/usr/local/bin/ruby[0x805ba84]
/usr/local/bin/ruby[0x8069e43]
/usr/local/bin/ruby[0x805d2be]
/usr/local/bin/ruby[0x8060b79]
======= Memory map: ========
08048000-080fb000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 745349                             /usr/local/bin/ruby
080fb000-080fc000 r--p 000b2000 ca:01 745349                             /usr/local/bin/ruby
080fc000-080fd000 rw-p 000b3000 ca:01 745349                             /usr/local/bin/ruby
080fd000-0810d000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
09fa2000-0cf87000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
f68d4000-f6c6f000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
f6ed9000-f6ee6000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 743029                             /lib/libgcc_s.so.1
f6ee6000-f6ee7000 r--p 0000c000 ca:01 743029                             /lib/libgcc_s.so.1
f6ee7000-f6ee8000 rw-p 0000d000 ca:01 743029                             /lib/libgcc_s.so.1
f6ef6000-f6f06000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 1523795                            /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libresolv-2.8.90.so
f6f06000-f6f07000 r--p 0000f000 ca:01 1523795                            /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libresolv-2.8.90.so
f6f07000-f6f08000 rw-p 00010000 ca:01 1523795                            /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libresolv-2.8.90.so
f6f08000-f6f0a000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
f6f0a000-f6f0e000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 1523788                            /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libnss_dns-2.8.90.so
f6f0e000-f6f0f000 r--p 00003000 ca:01 1523788                            /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libnss_dns-2.8.90.so
f6f0f000-f6f10000 rw-p 00004000 ca:01 1523788                            /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libnss_dns-2.8.90.so
f6f10000-f6f12000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 743040                             /lib/libnss_mdns4_minimal.so.2
f6f12000-f6f13000 rw-p 00001000 ca:01 743040                             /lib/libnss_mdns4_minimal.so.2
f6f1b000-f7122000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
f7122000-f712c000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 807183                             /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.8/i686-linux/socket.so
f712c000-f712d000 r--p 00009000 ca:01 807183                             /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.8/i686-linux/socket.so
f712d000-f712e000 rw-p 0000a000 ca:01 807183                             /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.8/i686-linux/socket.so
f712e000-f7131000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 807158                             /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.8/i686-linux/digest.so
f7131000-f7132000 r--p 00002000 ca:01 807158                             /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.8/i686-linux/digest.so
f7132000-f7133000 rw-p 00003000 ca:01 807158                             /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.8/i686-linux/digest.so
f7133000-f7147000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 745216                             /usr/lib/libz.so.1.2.3.3
f7147000-f7149000 rw-p 00013000 ca:01 745216                             /usr/lib/libz.so.1.2.3.3
f7149000-f727c000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 32847                              /usr/lib/i686/cmov/libcrypto.so.0.9.8
f727c000-f7284000 r--p 00132000 ca:01 32847                              /usr/lib/i686/cmov/libcrypto.so.0.9.8
f7284000-f7291000 rw-p 0013a000 ca:01 32847                              /usr/lib/i686/cmov/libcrypto.so.0.9.8
f7291000-f7295000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
f7295000-f72d7000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 32848                              /usr/lib/i686/cmov/libssl.so.0.9.8
f72d7000-f72d8000 ---p 00042000 ca:01 32848                              /usr/lib/i686/cmov/libssl.so.0.9.8
f72d8000-f72d9000 r--p 00042000 ca:01 32848                              /usr/lib/i686/cmov/libssl.so.0.9.8
f72d9000-f72dc000 rw-p 00043000 ca:01 32848                              /usr/lib/i686/cmov/libssl.so.0.9.8
f72dc000-f7313000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 807173                             /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.8/i686-linux/openssl.so
f7313000-f7314000 r--p 00036000 ca:01 807173                             /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.8/i686-linux/openssl.so
f7314000-f7315000 rw-p 00037000 ca:01 807173                             /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.8/i686-linux/openssl.so
f7315000-f7432000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
f7432000-f743c000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 1523789                            /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libnss_files-2.8.90.so
f743c000-f743d000 r--p 00009000 ca:01 1523789                            /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libnss_files-2.8.90.so
f743d000-f743e000 rw-p 0000a000 ca:01 1523789                            /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libnss_files-2.8.90.so
f743e000-f7447000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 1523791                            /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libnss_nis-2.8.90.so
f7447000-f7448000 r--p 00008000 ca:01 1523791                            /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libnss_nis-2.8.90.soAborted
cerne@rack02:~$
```

**Metadata file containing gemspec as yaml**

```
--- !ruby/object:Gem::Specification 
name: ginjo-rfm
version: !ruby/object:Gem::Version 
  hash: 15
  prerelease: 
  segments: 
  - 2
  - 0
  - 0
  version: 2.0.0
platform: ruby
authors: 
- Geoff Coffey
- Mufaddal Khumri
- Atsushi Matsuo
- Larry Sprock
- Bill Richardson
autorequire: 
bindir: bin
cert_chain: []

date: 2012-01-08 00:00:00 Z
dependencies: 
- !ruby/object:Gem::Dependency 
  name: activesupport
  prerelease: false
  requirement: &id001 !ruby/object:Gem::Requirement 
    none: false
    requirements: 
    - - ">="
      - !ruby/object:Gem::Version 
        hash: 9
        segments: 
        - 2
        - 3
        - 5
        version: 2.3.5
  type: :runtime
  version_requirements: *id001
- !ruby/object:Gem::Dependency 
  name: activemodel
  prerelease: false
  requirement: &id002 !ruby/object:Gem::Requirement 
    none: false
    requirements: 
    - - ">="
      - !ruby/object:Gem::Version 
        hash: 3
        segments: 
        - 0
        version: "0"
  type: :development
  version_requirements: *id002
- !ruby/object:Gem::Dependency 
  name: rake
  prerelease: false
  requirement: &id003 !ruby/object:Gem::Requirement 
    none: false
    requirements: 
    - - ">="
      - !ruby/object:Gem::Version 
        hash: 3
        segments: 
        - 0
        version: "0"
  type: :development
  version_requirements: *id003
- !ruby/object:Gem::Dependency 
  name: rdoc
  prerelease: false
  requirement: &id004 !ruby/object:Gem::Requirement 
    none: false
    requirements: 
    - - ">="
      - !ruby/object:Gem::Version 
        hash: 3
        segments: 
        - 0
        version: "0"
  type: :development
  version_requirements: *id004
- !ruby/object:Gem::Dependency 
  name: rspec
  prerelease: false
  requirement: &id005 !ruby/object:Gem::Requirement 
    none: false
    requirements: 
    - - ~>
      - !ruby/object:Gem::Version 
        hash: 27
        segments: 
        - 1
        - 3
        - 0
        version: 1.3.0
  type: :development
  version_requirements: *id005
- !ruby/object:Gem::Dependency 
  name: diff-lcs
  prerelease: false
  requirement: &id006 !ruby/object:Gem::Requirement 
    none: false
    requirements: 
    - - ">="
      - !ruby/object:Gem::Version 
        hash: 3
        segments: 
        - 0
        version: "0"
  type: :development
  version_requirements: *id006
- !ruby/object:Gem::Dependency 
  name: yard
  prerelease: false
  requirement: &id007 !ruby/object:Gem::Requirement 
    none: false
    requirements: 
    - - ">="
      - !ruby/object:Gem::Version 
        hash: 3
        segments: 
        - 0
        version: "0"
  type: :development
  version_requirements: *id007
- !ruby/object:Gem::Dependency 
  name: libxml-ruby
  prerelease: false
  requirement: &id008 !ruby/object:Gem::Requirement 
    none: false
    requirements: 
    - - ">="
      - !ruby/object:Gem::Version 
        hash: 3
        segments: 
        - 0
        version: "0"
  type: :development
  version_requirements: *id008
- !ruby/object:Gem::Dependency 
  name: nokogiri
  prerelease: false
  requirement: &id009 !ruby/object:Gem::Requirement 
    none: false
    requirements: 
    - - ">="
      - !ruby/object:Gem::Version 
        hash: 3
        segments: 
        - 0
        version: "0"
  type: :development
  version_requirements: *id009
- !ruby/object:Gem::Dependency 
  name: hpricot
  prerelease: false
  requirement: &id010 !ruby/object:Gem::Requirement 
    none: false
    requirements: 
    - - ">="
      - !ruby/object:Gem::Version 
        hash: 3
        segments: 
        - 0
        version: "0"
  type: :development
  version_requirements: *id010
- !ruby/object:Gem::Dependency 
  name: ox
  prerelease: false
  requirement: &id011 !ruby/object:Gem::Requirement 
    none: false
    requirements: 
    - - ">="
      - !ruby/object:Gem::Version 
        hash: 3
        segments: 
        - 0
        version: "0"
  type: :development
  version_requirements: *id011
description: Rfm lets your Ruby scripts and Rails applications talk directly to your Filemaker server. Ginjo-rfm includes ActiveModel compatibility, multiple XML parsers, compound Filemaker find requests, and a configuration API.
email: http://groups.google.com/group/rfmcommunity
executables: []

extensions: []

extra_rdoc_files: 
- LICENSE
- README.md
- CHANGELOG.md
- lib/rfm/VERSION
files: 
- lib/rfm/base.rb
- lib/rfm/database.rb
- lib/rfm/error.rb
- lib/rfm/layout.rb
- lib/rfm/metadata/field.rb
- lib/rfm/metadata/field_control.rb
- lib/rfm/metadata/script.rb
- lib/rfm/metadata/value_list_item.rb
- lib/rfm/record.rb
- lib/rfm/resultset.rb
- lib/rfm/server.rb
- lib/rfm/utilities/case_insensitive_hash.rb
- lib/rfm/utilities/compound_query.rb
- lib/rfm/utilities/config.rb
- lib/rfm/utilities/core_ext.rb
- lib/rfm/utilities/factory.rb
- lib/rfm/utilities/xml_parser.rb
- lib/rfm/version.rb
- lib/rfm/xml_mini/hpricot.rb
- lib/rfm/xml_mini/ox_sax.rb
- lib/rfm/xml_mini/rexml_sax.rb
- lib/rfm.rb
- lib/rfm/VERSION
- LICENSE
- README.md
- CHANGELOG.md
homepage: https://rubygems.org/gems/ginjo-rfm
licenses: []

post_install_message: 
rdoc_options: 
- --line-numbers
- --main
- README.md
require_paths: 
- lib
required_ruby_version: !ruby/object:Gem::Requirement 
  none: false
  requirements: 
  - - ">="
    - !ruby/object:Gem::Version 
      hash: 3
      segments: 
      - 0
      version: "0"
required_rubygems_version: !ruby/object:Gem::Requirement 
  none: false
  requirements: 
  - - ">"
    - !ruby/object:Gem::Version 
      hash: 25
      segments: 
      - 1
      - 3
      - 1
      version: 1.3.1
requirements: []

rubyforge_project: 
rubygems_version: 1.8.10
signing_key: 
specification_version: 3
summary: Ruby to Filemaker adapter
test_files: []

has_rdoc:
```

Comment: The multi json dependency is probably coming from active support (in versions >= 3.1 I think)

Comment: That's what I think too. But I don't understand why it's tripping me up when I already have ActiveSupport 2.3.5 installed. I wonder if there's something wrong with my gemspec that's causing rubygems to skip the installed ActiveSupport and instead look for v3.1.

Comment: Ugh, it doesn't appear to be a dependency problem, or at least not a problem with the listed gemspec dependencies. I removed all dependencies from the gemspec, and I still get the multi_json error on Snow Leopard and the buffer overflow error on Ubuntu 8.10. So... there must be a problem somewhere in the code of my gem. Does rubygems actually load the gem during the install process?

Comment: I must be loosing my mind. I removed the activesupport dependency from a test copy of ginjo-rfm again, and now the gem install errors have stopped. I'm going to let this go as a pitfall of using older versions of rubygems and activesupport.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your RubyGems version is out-of-date. Simply do this:

```
sudo gem update --system
```

and then:

```
sudo gem install rails
```

Tested and works on Mac OS X Snow Leopard 10.6.8.

Comment: Yep: 1.3.x is about 2 years old. Save yourself some grief and update it.

Comment: Just to follow up, I think this was definitely the issue. I've been using RVM to install much more recent rubies & rubygems, and I haven't run into this problem since.